# Написал тест, затем создал метод, почему то тест не проходит

Tags: java, исключения

```
@Test
void divisionOnZeroExceptionTest() {
    mathTest.setA(15);
    mathTest.setB(0);
    log.info("Division({}, {}) = {}", mathTest.getA(), mathTest.getB(), test.division());
    Assertions.assertThrows(ArithmeticException.class, () -> {
        test.division();
    });
}
```

Вот мой тест, а вот метод где я хочу чтобы при делении на ноль у меня выбрасывало исключение

```
public double division() {
    try {
        return math.getA() / math.getB();
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        throw new ArithmeticException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажи создание переменных `mathTest` и `test`, а также код классов, которым они принадлежат.

Comment: class MathOperationsServiceTest {

    private static MathOperations mathTest;
    private static MathOperationsService test;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MathOperationsServiceTest.class);

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {

        mathTest = new MathOperations();
        test = new MathOperationsService(mathTest);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как Вы думаете, вот эта строчка что делает? -

```
log.info("Division({}, {}) = {}", mathTest.getA(), mathTest.getB(), test.division());
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Закомментируйте ее.

Или

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)
```

Тогда не нужен `Assertions.assertThrows...`.

Comment: это строчка выводит сообщение, а так как вы написали это 4-ый Junit, у меня 5-ый

Comment: @LE_1984 Нет, эта строчка ничего не выводит. Почему?

Comment: Выводит вот это

Comment: [main] INFO  com.avp.lesson1.task3_mathOperations.service.MathOperationsServiceTest  - Division(15.0, 0.0) = Infinity

Comment: я так понимаю, что сам метод не правильно написан

Comment: перепесал метод, все работает, но вы были правы, на счет закоментить logger...это из-за того что выскакивала ошибка при вызове метода и программа останавливалась?

Comment: @LE_1984 Да, из-за этого.